# Multiple Text Cursors in TexStudio

Tags: texstudio, keyboard

I use TexStudio, and when I type there are multiple text cursors. Only one of them flashes, which is the actual one (i.e. the one where symbols appear when I type). But if I click somewhere else sometimes a non-flashing text cursor stays in that spot, like a residue (see image below, where there are three). It's not a serious problem, but it is somewhat annoying. I would just like there to be one cursor, the actual (flashing) one. I've tried updating TexStudio, but that hasn't helped. Any ideas? Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems to be a problem of the editor, texstudio, a good idea would be to expose the problem, in the Texstudio problem tracker, https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/issues, which you can find in the official site https://www.texstudio.org/ of texstudio, since, as you can notice, in most of the cases the problems are solved. I hope you find the information useful.